# Tenor GIF bot not really working, spits out error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, gif

I am still new to coding, but I have made a Discord bot recently that can fetch gifs via the Tenor API. It actually works until I put parameters in order for it to understand searches. This is the code that I had written (meaning obviously noob code that i have seen on a tutorial):

```
else if (tokens[0] === '!gif') {
         
        let keywords = "flower pots";
        if (tokens.length > 1){
            keywords = tokens.slice(1, tokens.length).join(" ")

        }
        let url = `https://api.tenor.com/v1/search?q=${keywords}&key=${tenorapikeyredacted}&contentfilter=low`;
        let response = await fetch(url);
        let json = await response.json();
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * json.results.length);
        message.channel.send(json.results[index].url);
        message.channel.send('The GIFS are working.');}
        }
```

The other features of the bot worked fine, it's just this one that I have problems with. So I ran it, entered the gif command, no answer, and my terminal spews out this error:

const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * json.results.length);
^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Client. (/Users/[userfolder]/[botfolder]/index.js:46:67)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Comment: Are you sure you need to .join(" ")  on a blank space? Try with a comma instead .join(",")

Comment: I could, pretty much. Thank you.